# FileSystem mocking using mockito

Tags: java, hadoop, mockito, junit4

I am a newbie on Mockito. I wanted to test a method which has a line:

```
RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> it = fileSystem.listFiles(file, true);
```

I have mocked filesystem instance here, and then i used the below :

```
File sourceDirectory = temporaryFolder.newFolder("sourceDirectory");
Path sourceDirectoryPath = new Path(sourceDirectory.toString());
File hdfsFile1 = new File(sourceDirectory.getAbsolutePath().toString(), "hdfsFile1.txt");
File hdfsFile2 = new File(sourceDirectory.getAbsolutePath().toString(), "hdfsFile2.txt");
FileSystem fileSystem = Mockito.mock(FileSystem.class);
RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> it = 
fileSystem.listFiles(sourceDirectoryPath, true);
when(fileSystem.listFiles(sourceDirectoryPath, true)).thenReturn(it);
```

But still i get the it as NULL. i want to get a valid RemoteIterator iterator.

How to accomplish that ? Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

Move this line:

```
when(fileSystem.listFiles(sourceDirectoryPath, true)).thenReturn(it);
```

Before calling metod `listFiles`, and you have also have the content you want to this mock to return:

```
//mock or provide real implementation of what has to be returned from filesystem mock
RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> it = (RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus>) Mockito.mock(RemoteIterator.class);
LocatedFileStatus myFileStatus = new LocatedFileStatus();
when(it.hasNext()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
when(it.next()).thenReturn(myFileStatus).thenReturn(null);
//mock the file system and make it return above content
FileSystem fileSystem = Mockito.mock(FileSystem.class);
when(fileSystem.listFiles(sourceDirectoryPath, true)).thenReturn(it);

RemoteIterator<LocatedFileStatus> files =
        fileSystem.listFiles(sourceDirectoryPath, true);

assertThat(files.hasNext()).isTrue();
assertThat(files.next()).isEqualTo(myFileStatus);
assertThat(files.hasNext()).isFalse();
```

In general you define the mock `whens` before doing the stuff you want to mock. You have to prepare the content of what the mocked object will return, then you define the `when` statements where you instruct your mocked object what it has to return when called.

Comment: But this throw error because 'it' is not defined at that stage. Dont you think so ?

Comment: Right, I miss noticed that malfunction in your code. I edited my answer.